# Kali wireless can't detect available wifi connections

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

While installing Kali (Dual Boot) the installation process could not detect network even after having all the drivers. Well after the installation is complete there were no wireless connection showing. I really tried a variety of things, but I couldn't fix the problem. Even after installing (unloading and loading) compat wireless it shows wlan0 and wlan1 but they couldn't detect any wireless network ever. wlan0 up commands are also seeming useless in my case. Please help me... 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please edit your question and give more information about the wifi card : `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` and `uname -a`

Comment: Thanks for reply... I solved the problem yesterday by running the following commands... : `apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms` and `modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma` then `modprobe wl` no other comments even upgrade had not worked, but at last this helped me.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by doing this ,

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

if it don't work for you use this [debian tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/wl) for enable wifi devices

adding something more -- actually I think I had some headers problem, So this type of commands for installing drivers won't help me. At last I could fix the thing by running the command below,

```
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
modprobe wl
```

Comment: How do you know the wireless card model?

Comment: If you are Pallab Dutta then please have your accounts joined, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.

Comment: nope this does not work...

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved !!!
Actually I think I had some headers problem, So this type of commands for installing drivers won't help me. At last I could fix the thing by running the command below,

```
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
modprobe wl
```

after rebooting my problems were fixed. :) One thing more sometimes you may have problems with sudo apt-get update. ( for my case previously it showed nothing at all ) First I had to fix that problem. Then I did this. I think this will help you.
I got the code line from this video
  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5wXFkL2p2k